# protractor sendKeys not fill all string in input box

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

> [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/ffcd7072-9f96-45cb-a61d-ec53fc696b56/element/0.9513211246393813-32/value {"value":["1","0","0","0","1"],"text":"10001"}

My code:

```
this.zipcode = element(by.model('personalInfo.zipcode'));

 this.setZipcode = function (inputStr) {
    this.zipcode.clear().sendKeys(inputStr);
};
```

I pass 10001 in "inputStr" but only 101 or 1 or 100 filled in input

Comment: What do you see entered in the input?

Comment: only single digit => 1

Comment: Okay, have you tried sending keys as a string: `zipcode.sendKeys("10001")`;?

Comment: nop, let me check

Comment: Actuall, i used pageObject.
this.zipcode = element(by.model('info.zipcode'));
this.setZipcode = function (inputStr) {
        this.zipcode.clear();
        this.zipcode.clear().sendKeys(inputStr);
};

Comment: Not working this.    zipcode.sendKeys("10001");

Comment: Okay. What if you would first do `this.zipcode.clear()` then `browser.sleep(1000)` and only then `this.zipcode.sendKeys("10001");`?

Comment: still same issue. only => "101" display in input box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161884/discussion-between-alecxe-and-uttam-panara).

Comment: I met similar situation if the input box bind some event like keyUp/keyDown by developer who intend to validate user input a valid zipcode or not.  The keyUp/keyDown event seems will break the normal sendKeys().  If you are in this case, you can use driver.executeScript() to set the zip code by javascript in background, rather from fontend.

Comment: exactly, i think ng-change event is break my code.

Comment: but i need ng-change event also. have any solution both work sendKeys() and ng-change works together

Comment: Can you share the relevant `HTML` ?

Comment: You can use driver.executeScript() to input the zip code, after that you can send a Tab key to trigger ng-change event.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably there is logic running while you input the ZIP code. The logic seems to look up the matching municipality and while doing so blocks from further input.

Please check, if you can manually reproduce this user experience (on fast input, some digits are ignored).

This is more likely a user experience bug of the software under test than a protractor issue.

Suggestion for the software is to run the logic after 1 sec of idle or to not block input while running the logic (go async).